# i want to convert "Milano\u0093Deepak Gupta\u0094" into String in java

Tags: java, utf-8, decode, encode

i want to convert  below string in UTF-8 string in java

```
String s= "Milano\u0093Deepak Gupta\u0094";
```

Answer (score 2):

All strings are internally stored as **UTF-16** in java. This is the reason for string containing \u0093 etc.The below piece of code can be used to convert to **UTF-8**

```
try {
    // Convert from Unicode to UTF-8
    String string = "\u003c";
    byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Convert from UTF-8 to Unicode
    string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
}
```